# How to do editable table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I had a table in which fields are editable.The problem is when i edit a field then the remaining fields are moving out of table.I put a screen shot below
[image]

[image]

Can any one suggest help please.

My Html

```
<table class="table table-hover">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th class="hidden-xs-down">#</th>
                 <th>Account Name</th>
                 <th class="hidden-xs-down">Phone</th>
                 <th class="hidden-xs-down">Account Name ALias</th>
                 <th></th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor = 'let student of students'>
                 <td class="hidden-xs-down">1</td>
                 <td contenteditable="true">
                    <a>{{student.accountname}}</a>
                 </td>
                 <td contenteditable="true" style="max-width:300px;" class ='phone'>
                    {{student.phone}}   
                 </td><i class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i>
                 <td contenteditable="true">
                    {{student.accountownername}}
                 </td>
                 <td>

              </tr>

           </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: not really an answer, but have you seen http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/editable.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly set max-width on a td element. You can set width or maybe truncate the string with:

```
    .truncate {
      width: 300px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```